# Download image from Imagelibrary

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, event-receivers, image

I have an event receiver that should download images from an imagelibrary, and do some stuff with that copy. There will be several images with the same customid that i want to grab, so I loop over all images and select images with correct id.

How can manage to get the specific item, but how do I grab the file in that item and pass it off as for example a bitmap?

So far I've got this:

```
//tempid is the value Im looking for in the library
tempid = 1000;
SPListItemCollection Images = pictureLib.Items;
for(int i = 0;i<pictureLib.ItemCount;i++)
{
    //get a specific lookupid,the one im im looking for.
    SPFielLookupValue value = new SPFieldLookupValue(itemid,ObjectId);
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    if(tempid == id)
    { 
        //Here is where i want the bitmap.
        System.Drawing.Bitmap img = Images[i].File;
        ...
     }
 }
```

So within the "if" I want to get a bitmap from the SPListItemCollection, but how do i get that, is it possible? Is there a method on SPListItemCollection I can use, either "File" or "Attachment", or do I have to convert the file to bitmap first?

Much appreciated any help or ideas here. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a MemoryStream to create an Image object from the file:

```
var imageFile = Images[i].File;
var imageStream = imageFile.OpenBinaryStream();
Image image = Image.FromStream(imageStream, true, true);
imageStream.Dispose();
```

Depending on what you need to do, this can be done from the Image, like resizing

```
if (originalImage.Width > MAX_WIDTH)// || originalImage.Height > MAX_HEIGHT)
                {
                    var ratioX = (double)MAX_WIDTH / originalImage.Width;
                    //var ratioY = (double)MAX_HEIGHT / originalImage.Height;
                    var ratio = ratioX;// Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

                    var newWidth = (int)(originalImage.Width * ratio);
                    var newHeight = (int)(originalImage.Height * ratio);

                    var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                    Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                    byte[] smallImage = ImageToByteArray(newImage, originalImage.RawFormat);
                }
```